# matlab objective funtion must return a scalar value

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand now fminunc (fmincon) works, however I keep getting error.

When I use documentation example with two variables

```
fun = @(x)3*x(1)^2 + 2*x(1)*x(2) + x(2)^2 - 4*x(1) + 5*x(2);
x0 = [1,1];
[x,fval] = fminunc(fun,x0);
```

everything works fine.

Hovewer, when I am trying to fit a plane for 3 points, 
the code does not work

```
n0 = [ 0  1 -2; 
       1  2  1;
      -2 -4 -4]
fun = @(x) [x(1) x(2) x(3)] * n0 - [1 1 1]
```

The task for fminunc is just an example. I know I can solve it easily analytically.

Comment: It is because the function must return a scalar value

Comment: try something like `fun = @(x) norm([x(1) x(2) x(3)] * n0 - [1 1 1])^2;`

Comment: what should I do if I need 3 return values?

Comment: @Vittori0 `fminunc` will give 3 values. but the **cost function** should return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost function returns a scalar. What you have written returns a [1x3] matrix. You could try something like this if you want to minimise the euclidean distance

```
fun = @(x) sum(([x(1) x(2) x(3)] * n0 - [1 1 1]).^2);
```

Comment: but in example in my question above it returns 2 values
x =
    2.2500   -4.7500
(from official documentation)
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html?searchHighlight=fminunc&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Comment: More mathematically sound, you may want to minimize the 2 norm: `norm([x(1) x(2) x(3)] * n0 - [1 1 1])`. (Its the same thing)

Comment: @Vittori0 You may not be understanding how minimisation works. When minimising, you need 1 value to say "this is better". How can the algorithm know if something is better with 3 values? The classic way is computing the L2 norm, or euclidean norm. This norm will give smaller values if they are closer. The official documentation agrees

Comment: The objective function **has** to compute a scalar for the given x, like explained above. The input x, however, can have any dimensions. In the example x is two dimensional, but the function still returns a scalar if you look carefully. However, the x which satisfies the minimisation is two dimensional.